# How Google App Engine limit Python?

Tags: python, hosting, shared-hosting

Does anybody know, how GAE limit Python interpreter? For example, how they block IO operations, or URL operations.

Shared hosting also do it in some way?

Comment: Well, first off, you can only use Python 2.5

Comment: Yes. Only 2.5. But how does "sandbox" internaly works?

Comment: The OP is looking for **How** is AppEngine blocking/limiting python's access to the os, rather than **What** are they limiting.  I think @Anton want's to know Google's technique/approach to building a sandbox like the one used by GAE.

Comment: Ahhh, ok thanks that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sandbox "internally works" by them having a special version of the Python interpreter. You aren't running the standard Python executable, but one especially modified to run on Google App engine.

Update:

And no it's not a virtual machine in the ordinary sense. Each application does not have a complete virtual PC. There may be some virtualization going on, but Google isn't saying exactly how much or what.

A process has normally in an operating system already limited access to the rest of the OS and the hardware. Google have limited this even more and you get an environment where you are only allowed to read the very specific parts of the file system, and not write to it at all, you are not allowed to open sockets and not allowed to make system calls etc.

I don't know at which level OS/Filesystem/Interpreter each limitation is implemented, though.

Answer (score 1):

From Google's site:

- An application can only access other
  computers on the Internet through the
  provided URL fetch and email
  services. Other computers can only
  connect to the application by making
  HTTP (or HTTPS) requests on the
  standard ports.
- An application cannot write to the
  file system. An app can read files,
  but only files uploaded with the
  application code. The app must use
  the App Engine datastore, memcache or
  other services for all data that
  persists between requests.
- Application code only runs in
  response to a web request, a queued
  task, or a scheduled task, and must
  return response data within 30
  seconds in any case. A request
  handler cannot spawn a sub-process or
  execute code after the response has
  been sent.

Beyond that, you're stuck with Python 2.5, you can't use any C-based extensions, more up-to-date versions of web frameworks won't work in some cases (Python 2.5 again).

You can read the whole article [What is Google App Engine?](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html).

Comment: Does it use single VM for each app?

Comment: @Anton I'm not certain of the implementation details, but you can probably think of the sandbox as a VM.

Answer (score 0):

### I found this site

that has some pretty decent information.  What exactly are you trying to do?

[Here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html)

### FRESH!

Look here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html

Your IO Operations are limited as follows (beyond disabled modules):

> App Engine records how much of each resource an application uses in a calendar day, and considers the resource depleted when this amount reaches the app's quota for the resource. A calendar day is a period of 24 hours beginning at midnight, Pacific Time. App Engine resets all resource measurements at the beginning of each day, except for Stored Data which always represents the amount of datastore storage in use.
>
> When an app consumes all of an allocated resource, the resource becomes unavailable until the quota is replenished. This may mean that your app will not work until the quota is replenished.
>
> An application can determine how much CPU time the current request has taken so far by calling the Quota API. This is useful for profiling CPU-intensive code, and finding places where CPU efficiency can be improved for greater cost savings. You can measure the CPU used for the entire request, or call the API before and after a section of code then subtract to determine the CPU used between those two points.

Resource|   Free Default Quota| Billing Enabled Default Quota
Blobstore |Stored Data| 1 GB|   1 GB free; no maximum
Resource    |Billing Enabled| Default Quota
Daily Limit|    Maximum Rate
Blobstore API Calls |140,000,000 calls| 72,000 calls/minute

Hmm my table isn't that good, but hopefully still readable.

EDIT:  OK, I understand.  But sir, you did not have to use the "f" word.  :)  And you know, it's kinda like the whole 'teach a man to fish' scenario.  Google is who I always ask and that's why I'm answering questions here for fun.

EDIT AGAIN:  OK that made more sense before the comment was tooked.  So I went and answered the question a little more.  I hope it helps.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a question and a comment. It's the difference between being rude and being honest. You should only leave an answer if you have something helpful to say.

Comment: I really thought providing a link directly to the information was sort of helpful, but I guess not so I just read it myself and pasted some pieces here.  Very interesting read!  I recommend it to anyone, especially if you are on StackOverflow asking questions about the subject.

Comment: It is interesting, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: In what way do those pages not answer the question? http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#UrlFetch http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Requests EDIT: OK he wants to know HOW he can achieve the same thing as them, not what they are limiting or blocking.  Touché.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's not a standard python, but a version specifically patched for app engine. In other words you can think more or less like an "higher level" VM that however is not emulating x86 instructions but python opcodes (if you don't know what they are try writing a small function named "foo" and the doing "import dis; dis.dis(foo)" you will see the python opcodes that the compiler produced).

By patching python you can impose to it whatever limitations you like. Of course you've however to forbid the use of user supplied C/C++ extension modules as a C/C++ module will have access to everything the process can access.

Using such a virtual environment you're able to run safely python code without the need to use a separate x86 VM for every instance.